# AWS' RDS DB proxy authorization failure when cutting-over between RDS instances

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS DB proxy that I'm using to cut-over from my old RDS instance to a new RDS instance. The RDS instances are Postgres engines. However, after changing target groups, the proxy fails to use the correct secret to connect to the new target group. This is the behavior associated with the problem:

For ease of describing the problem, I’ll refer to the following resources using a shorthand.

- O = Old RDS instance
- O<sup>P</sup>  = Old RDS instance’s password
- N = New RDS instance
- N<sup>P</sup> = New RDS instance's password
- DBP->O = when the old RDS instance is the DB Proxy's target group
- DBP->N = when the new RDS instance is the DB Proxy's target group

1. First I configure the old RDS instance (O) as the DB proxy's target group. The proxy only has the secret containing O<sup>P</sup> in the "Authentication" section. The proxy can successfully connect to O.

| Secret(s) in "Authentication" Section | Target Group | Target Group available? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O<sup>P</sup> | DBP->O | Yes |

2. Next, in preparation for cutting-over, I modify the proxy to have the secret for O<sup>P</sup> and the secret for N<sup>P</sup>. The proxy can successfully connect to O.

| Secret(s) in "Authentication" Section | Target Group | Target Group available? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O<sup>P</sup> and N<sup>P</sup> | DBP->O | Yes |

I modify the proxy's "Authorization" section by running this command:

```
user@host:~/$ AWS_PROFILE=profile aws rds modify-db-proxy \
--db-proxy-name pxy-name \
--auth '[
{"AuthScheme": "SECRETS", "SecretArn": "'${OLD_RDS_INSTANCE_SECRET}'", "IAMAuth": "DISABLED" },
{"AuthScheme": "SECRETS", "SecretArn": "'${NEW_RDS_INSTANCE_SECRET}'", "IAMAuth": "DISABLED" }]'
```

3. Then I cut-over to the new RDS instance.

| Secret(s) in "Authentication" Section | Target Group | Target Group available? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| O<sup>P</sup> and N<sup>P</sup> | DBP->N | No |

I get the following authorization error:

```
user@host:~/$ AWS_PROFILE=profile aws rds describe-db-proxy-targets --db-proxy-name pxy-name
{
    "Targets": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "rds-endpoint",
            "RdsResourceId": "New-rds-resource-id",
            "Port": 5432,
            "Type": "RDS_INSTANCE",
            "Role": "READ_WRITE",
            "TargetHealth": {
                "State": "UNAVAILABLE",
                "Reason": "AUTH_FAILURE",
                "Description": "Database authentication failed with provided user credentials"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

3. To fix the authorization error, I remove O<sup>P</sup> from the "Authentication" section.

| Secret(s) in "Authentication" Section | Target Group | Target Group available? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| N<sup>P</sup> | DBP->N | Yes |

To remove O<sup>P</sup> from the "Authentication" section, I modify the proxy only have N<sup>P</sup>:

```
user@host:~/$ AWS_PROFILE=profile aws rds modify-db-proxy \
--db-proxy-name pxy-name \
--auth '[
{"AuthScheme": "SECRETS", "SecretArn": "'${NEW_RDS_INSTANCE_SECRET}'", "IAMAuth": "DISABLED" }]'
```

If I do steps 1-4, starting with DBP->N, I get the same behavior. My impression is that these DB proxies were designed and tested to work with one RDs instance and one RDS instance only.

Modifying the proxy before cut-over isn't an ideal solution because it adds downtime while I wait for the proxy to finish modifying. Has anyone else encountered this bug and found a good workaround?